# Open-Xchange - Email client connection

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

Just installed Open-Xchange community on debian squeeze, I can access my email by going to http://ox.mysite.co.uk/ and all is well however how do I connect my email client thunderbird to get mail, I found the thunderbird extender and that hooks up calendar and contacts but no mail, the only way I think is to hook up directly to my mail server and grab mail from there but I was under the impression that open exchange would deal with the fetching of mail from the mail server.

I have tried connecting to the open-Xchange server via IMAP in thunderbird and I get connection refused and then i tried to telnet to the open-Xchange server via telnet on port 143 and I get connection refused, Then I tried telneting localhost 143 on the ox server itself and same thing connection refused.

Any help or advise would be greatly received.

Comment: It's "Open-Xchange", not "open-exchange". I corrected your post. Correct spelling is important particulary for product names, as otherwise search will not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Open-Xchange provides email access via POP3 or IMAP (like most mail servers). Just set up an IMAP (or POP3) mailbox in Thunderbird.

Thunderbird should have prompted you to set up an account when you installed it. Otherwise, just create one using the wizard. See e.g. http://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/automatic-account-configuration?s=create+account&as=s

*Edit:*

If you get "Connection refused" when contacting the server, the IMAP service is probably not running, or blocked by a firewall. Talk to your network administrator and/or the Open-Xchange server administrator.

Comment: Hi I have updated my question as Ive already tried connecting with thunderbird

Comment: Yeah I am the administrator, im just testing open xchange, however on there site it shows the ox server as being the internet facing box all end user devices connect to it and then the ox server does the heavy lifting of grabbing email from the mail-server however I cant find any info on itself being an imap server it certainly doesnt talk imap or pop when telneting it.

Comment: Sorry, can't really help you there, I don't know the architecture of Open-Xchange. Maybe IMAP needs to be enabled somewhere. Or does Open-Xchange use IMAP itself to fetch the mail for the webmail interface? Then you probably just need to connect to the original server for IMAP.

Comment: thats what im thinking it simply does webmail, calenders and contacts, and you connect to your mail servers directly which is what I have setup now and it works fine. Ill dig deeper. Thanks for the reply